# Electric force between particles using numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, physics, particles

I am trying to simulate a particle flying at another particle while undergoing electrical repulsion (or attraction), called Rutherford-scattering. I have succeeded in simulating (a few) particles using for loops and python lists. However, now I want to use numpy arrays instead. The model will use the following steps:

1. For all particles:

   1. Calculate radial distance with all other particles
   2. Calculate the angle with all other particles
   3. Calculate netto force in x-direction and y-direction
2. Create matrix with netto xForce and yForce for each particle
3. Create accelaration (also x and y component) matrix by a = F/mass
4. Update speed matrix
5. Update position matrix

My problem is that **I do not know how I can use numpy arrays in calculating the force components.**
Here follows my code which is not runnable.

```
import numpy as np
# I used this function to calculate the force while using for-loops.
def force(x1, y1, x2, x2):
    angle =  math.atan((y2 - y1)/(x2 - x1))
    dr = ((x1-x2)**2 + (y1-y2)**2)**0.5
    force = charge2 * charge2 / dr**2 
    xforce = math.cos(angle) * force 
    yforce = math.sin(angle) * force

    # The direction of force depends on relative location
    if x1 > x2 and y1<y2:
        xforce = xforce
        yforce = yforce
    elif x1< x2 and y1< y2:
        xforce = -1 * xforce
        yforce = -1 * yforce
    elif x1 > x2 and y1 > y2:
        xforce = xforce
        yforce = yforce
    else:
        xforce = -1 * xforce
        yforce = -1* yforce

    return xforce, yforce

def update(array):

    # this for loop defeats the entire use of numpy arrays
    for particle in range(len(array[0])):
        # find distance of all particles pov from 1 particle

        # find all x-forces and y-forces on that particle

        xforce = # sum of all x-forces from all particles
        yforce = # sum of all y-forces from all particles
        force_arr[0, particle] = xforce
        force_arr[1, particle] = yforce

    return force

# begin parameters
t = 0
N = 3
masses = np.ones(N)
charges = np.ones(N)
loc_arr = np.random.rand(2, N)
speed_arr = np.random.rand(2, N)
acc_arr = np.random.rand(2, N)
force = np.random.rand(2, N)


while t < 0.5:
    force_arr = update(loc_arry)
    acc_arr = force_arr / masses
    speed_arr += acc_array
    loc_arr += speed_arr
    t += dt

    # plot animation
```

Comment: This `# this for loop defeats the entire use of numpy arrays` suggests you want to avoid using loops, but an 'inline' computation? Perhaps vectorisation is the way to go: https://towardsdatascience.com/python-vectorization-5b882eeef658

Answer (score 4):

One approach to model this problem with arrays may be:

- define the point coordinates as a `Nx2` array.  (This will help with extensibility if you advance to 3-D points later)
- define the intermediate variables `distance`, `angle`, `force` as `NxN` arrays to represent the pairwise interactions

Numpy things to know about:

- You can call most numeric functions on arrays if the arrays have the same shape (or conforming shapes, which is a nontrivial topic...)
- `meshgrid` helps you generate the array indices necessary to shapeshift your `Nx2` arrays to compute `NxN` results
- and a tangential note (ha ha) `arctan2()` computes a signed angle, so you can bypass the complex "which quadrant" logic

For example you can do something like this.  Note in `get_dist` and `get_angle` the arithmetic operations between points take place in the bottom-most dimension:

```
import numpy as np

# 2-D locations of particles
points = np.array([[1,0],[2,1],[2,2]])
N = len(points)  # 3

def get_dist(p1, p2):
    r = p2 - p1
    return np.sqrt(np.sum(r*r, axis=2))

def get_angle(p1, p2):
    r = p2 - p1
    return np.arctan2(r[:,:,1], r[:,:,0])

ii = np.arange(N)
ix, iy = np.meshgrid(ii, ii)

dist = get_dist(points[ix], points[iy])
angle = get_angle(points[ix], points[iy])
# ... compute force
# ... apply the force, etc.
```

For the sample 3-point vector shown above:

```
In [246]: dist
Out[246]: 
array([[0.        , 1.41421356, 2.23606798],
       [1.41421356, 0.        , 1.        ],
       [2.23606798, 1.        , 0.        ]])

In [247]: angle / np.pi     # divide by Pi to make the numbers recognizable
Out[247]: 
array([[ 0.        , -0.75      , -0.64758362],
       [ 0.25      ,  0.        , -0.5       ],
       [ 0.35241638,  0.5       ,  0.        ]])
```

Comment: If you know you'll never need more than 2D, another approach is to model the points in the complex plane (`x -> Real`, `y -> Imag`), to keep your points in a nice tight vector.

Comment: Thank you for the tips. I will make sure to update my post when I have it working. Instead of ```get_dist```, I can also use ```distance.cdist(points, points)``` which give exactly the same output. I will probably go 3D as it is part of the assignment.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one go with only a loop for each time step, and it should work for any number of dimensions, I have tested with 3 too:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

N = 4
ndim = 2
masses = np.ones(N)
charges = np.array([-1, 1, -1, 1]) * 2
# loc_arr = np.random.rand(N, ndim)
loc_arr = np.array(((-1,0), (1,0), (0,-1), (0,1)), dtype=float)
speed_arr = np.zeros((N, ndim))

# compute charge matrix, ie c1 * c2
charge_matrix = -1 * np.outer(charges, charges)

time = np.linspace(0, 0.5)
dt = np.ediff1d(time).mean()

for i, t in enumerate(time):
    # get (dx, dy) for every point
    delta = (loc_arr.T[..., np.newaxis] - loc_arr.T[:, np.newaxis]).T
    # calculate Euclidean distance
    distances = np.linalg.norm(delta, axis=-1)
    # and normalised unit vector
    unit_vector = (delta.T / distances).T
    unit_vector[np.isnan(unit_vector)] = 0 # replace NaN values with 0

    # calculate force
    force = charge_matrix / distances**2 # norm gives length of delta vector
    force[np.isinf(force)] = 0 # NaN forces are 0

    # calculate acceleration in all dimensions
    acc = (unit_vector.T * force / masses).T.sum(axis=1)
    # v = a * dt
    speed_arr += acc * dt

    # increment position, xyz = v * dt
    loc_arr += speed_arr * dt 

    # plotting
    if not i:
        color = 'k'
        zorder = 3
        ms = 3
        for i, pt in enumerate(loc_arr):
            ax.text(*pt + 0.1, s='{}q {}m'.format(charges[i], masses[i]))
    elif i == len(time)-1:
        color = 'b'
        zroder = 3
        ms = 3
    else:
        color = 'r'
        zorder = 1
        ms = 1
    ax.plot(loc_arr[:,0], loc_arr[:,1], '.', color=color, ms=ms, zorder=zorder)

ax.set_aspect('equal')
```

The above example produces, where the black and blue points signify the start and end positions, respectively:

[image: initial example ±1 charges]

And when charges are equal `charges = np.ones(N) * 2` the system symmetry is preserved and the charges repel:

[image: +1 charges]

And finally with some random initial velocities `speed_arr = np.random.rand(N, 2)`:

[image: initial velocities]

EDIT

Made a small change to the code above to make sure it was correct. (I was missing -1 on the resultant force, ie. force between +/+ should be negative, and I was summing down the wrong axis, apologies for that. Now in the cases where `masses[0] = 5`, the system evolves correctly:

[image: masses[0] = 5]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! If I change the masses to not-equal values, it seems like the mass-list needs to be flipped around to make it work properly. Another issue I encounter, is that a particle with mass `10**99`, will still move quite a bit due to some electric force from particles with mass 1.

Comment: You are right! There were 2 slight errors in the code, I've corrected them now and the results are consistent. I've also added a larger mass example.

Comment: Thank you so much. I never would have thought a `-1*` and `axis=1` would fix it.

Answer (score 1):

The classic approach is to calculate electric field for all particles in the system. Say you have 3 charged particles all with positive charge:

```
particles = np.array([[1,0,0],[2,1,0],[2,2,0]]) # location of each particle
q = np.array([1,1,1]) # charge of each particle
```

The easiest way to compute the electric field at each particle`s location is for loop:

```
def for_method(pos,q):
    """Computes electric field vectors for all particles using for-loop."""
    Evect = np.zeros( (len(pos),len(pos[0])) ) # define output electric field vector
    k =  1 / (4 * np.pi * const.epsilon_0) * np.ones((len(pos),len(pos[0]))) * 1.602e-19 # make this into matrix as matrix addition is faster
    # alternatively you can get rid of np.ones and just define this as a number
    
    for i, v0 in enumerate(pos): # s_p - selected particle | iterate over all particles | v0 reference particle
        for v, qc in zip(pos,q): # loop over all particles and calculate electric force sum | v particle being calculated for
            if all((v0 == v)):   # do not compute for the same particle
                continue
            else:
                r = v0 - v       #
                Evect[i] += r / np.linalg.norm(r) ** 3 * qc #! multiply by charge
    return Evect * k
# to find electric field at each particle`s location call
for_method(particles, q)
```

This function returns array of vectors with the same shape as input *particles* array. To find force on each, you simply multiply this vector with *q* array of charges. From there on, you can easily find your acceleration and integrate the system using your favourite ODE solver.

### Performance Optimization & Accuracy

For method is the slowest possible approach. The field can be computed using solely linear algebra granting significant speed boost. Following code is very efficient Numpy matrix "one-liner" (almost one-liner) to this problem:

```
def CPU_matrix_method(pos,q):
    """Classic vectorization of for Coulomb law using numpy arrays."""
    k = 1 / (4 * np.pi * const.epsilon_0) * np.ones((len(pos),3)) * 1.602e-19 # define electric constant
    dist = distance.cdist(pos,pos)  # compute distances
    return k * np.sum( (( np.tile(pos,len(pos)).reshape((len(pos),len(pos),3)) - np.tile(pos,(len(pos),1,1))) * q.reshape(len(q),1)).T * np.power(dist,-3, where = dist != 0),axis = 1).T
```

**Note that this and following code also return electric field vector for each particle.**

You can get even higher performance if you offload this onto the GPU using Cupy library. Following code is almost identical to the *CPU_matrix_method*, I only expanded the one-liner a little so that you could see better what is going on:

```
def GPU_matrix_method(pos,q):
    """GPU Coulomb law vectorization.
    Takes in numpy arrays, performs computations and returns cupy array"""
    # compute distance matrix between each particle
    k_cp = 1 / (4 * cp.pi * const.epsilon_0) * cp.ones((len(pos),3)) * 1.602e-19 # define electric constant, runs faster if this is matrix
    dist = cp.array(distance.cdist(pos,pos)) # could speed this up with cupy cdist function! use this: cupyx.scipy.spatial.distance.cdist
    pos, q = cp.array(pos), cp.array(q) # load inputs to GPU memory
    dist_mod = cp.power(dist,-3)        # compute inverse cube of distance
    dist_mod[dist_mod == cp.inf] = 0    # set all infinity entries to 0 (i.e. diagonal elements/ same particle-particle pairs)
    # compute by magic
    return k_cp * cp.sum((( cp.tile(pos,len(pos)).reshape((len(pos),len(pos),3)) - cp.tile(pos,(len(pos),1,1))) * q.reshape(len(q),1)).T * dist_mod, axis = 1).T
```

Regarding the accuracy of the mentioned algorithms, if you compute the 3 methods on the *particles* array you get identical results:

```
[[-6.37828367e-10 -7.66608512e-10  0.00000000e+00]
 [ 5.09048221e-10 -9.30757576e-10  0.00000000e+00]
 [ 1.28780145e-10  1.69736609e-09  0.00000000e+00]]
```

Regarding the performance, I computed each algorithm on systems ranging from 2 to 5000 charged particles. Additionally I also included Numba precompiled version of the *for_method* to make the for-loop approach competitive:
[image: Performance chart for the 3 approaches.]
We see that for-loop performs terribly needing over 400 seconds to compute for system with 5000 particles. Zooming in to the bottom part:
[image: Close-up of the performance chart]
This shows that matrix approach to this problem is orders of magnitude better. To be exact the 5000 particle evaluation took 18.5s for Numba for-loop, 4s for CPU matrix(5 times faster than Numba), and 0.8s for GPU matrix*  (23 times faster than Numba). The significant difference shows for larger arrays.

* GPU used was Nvidia K100.